# Proteus program address is not within code memory

Tags: pic, proteus, mplabx, mplab

I am trying to simulate the following circuit with Proteus.

[image]

Both the crystal and PIC18F4550 frequency is 20MHz.
When I start the simulation, I get more than 100 messages:

- [PIC18 LOAD] Program address 0x00 ... is not within code memory.

However the code in MPLABx compiles me perfectly.
I add my code.

````
// 'C' source line config statements

// CONFIG1L
#pragma config PLLDIV = 1       // PLL Prescaler Selection bits (No prescale (4 MHz oscillator input drives PLL directly))
#pragma config CPUDIV = OSC1_PLL2// System Clock Postscaler Selection bits ([Primary Oscillator Src: /1][96 MHz PLL Src: /2])
#pragma config USBDIV = 1       // USB Clock Selection bit (used in Full-Speed USB mode only; UCFG:FSEN = 1) (USB clock source comes directly from the primary oscillator block with no postscale)

// CONFIG1H
#pragma config FOSC = HS        // Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator (HS))
#pragma config FCMEN = OFF      // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable bit (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor disabled)
#pragma config IESO = OFF       // Internal/External Oscillator Switchover bit (Oscillator Switchover mode disabled)

// CONFIG2L
#pragma config PWRT = ON        // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT enabled)
#pragma config BOR = OFF        // Brown-out Reset Enable bits (Brown-out Reset disabled in hardware and software)
#pragma config BORV = 3         // Brown-out Reset Voltage bits (Minimum setting 2.05V)
#pragma config VREGEN = OFF     // USB Voltage Regulator Enable bit (USB voltage regulator disabled)

// CONFIG2H
#pragma config WDT = OFF        // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled (control is placed on the SWDTEN bit))
#pragma config WDTPS = 32768    // Watchdog Timer Postscale Select bits (1:32768)

// CONFIG3H
#pragma config CCP2MX = ON      // CCP2 MUX bit (CCP2 input/output is multiplexed with RC1)
#pragma config PBADEN = ON      // PORTB A/D Enable bit (PORTB<4:0> pins are configured as analog input channels on Reset)
#pragma config LPT1OSC = OFF    // Low-Power Timer 1 Oscillator Enable bit (Timer1 configured for higher power operation)
#pragma config MCLRE = ON       // MCLR Pin Enable bit (MCLR pin enabled; RE3 input pin disabled)

// CONFIG4L
#pragma config STVREN = ON      // Stack Full/Underflow Reset Enable bit (Stack full/underflow will cause Reset)
#pragma config LVP = OFF        // Single-Supply ICSP Enable bit (Single-Supply ICSP disabled)
#pragma config ICPRT = OFF      // Dedicated In-Circuit Debug/Programming Port (ICPORT) Enable bit (ICPORT disabled)
#pragma config XINST = OFF      // Extended Instruction Set Enable bit (Instruction set extension and Indexed Addressing mode disabled (Legacy mode))

// CONFIG5L
#pragma config CP0 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) is not code-protected)
#pragma config CP1 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) is not code-protected)
#pragma config CP2 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) is not code-protected)
#pragma config CP3 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) is not code-protected)

// CONFIG5H
#pragma config CPB = OFF        // Boot Block Code Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) is not code-protected)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data EEPROM Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM is not code-protected)

// CONFIG6L
#pragma config WRT0 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) is not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT1 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) is not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT2 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) is not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT3 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) is not write-protected)

// CONFIG6H
#pragma config WRTC = OFF       // Configuration Register Write Protection bit (Configuration registers (300000-3000FFh) are not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTB = OFF       // Boot Block Write Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) is not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTD = OFF       // Data EEPROM Write Protection bit (Data EEPROM is not write-protected)

// CONFIG7L
#pragma config EBTR0 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR1 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR2 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR3 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

// CONFIG7H
#pragma config EBTRB = OFF      // Boot Block Table Read Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.

#define _XTAL_FREQ 20000000L

#include <xc.h>

char contador = 1;
long speed = 1;
void Led1(void);
void Led2(void);
void Led3(void);
void Led4(void);

void initPort(void){
    ADCON1bits.PCFG = 11111111;
    LATD = 00000000;
    LATB = 00000000;
    TRISBbits.RB0 = 1;
    TRISBbits.RB1 = 1;
    INTCON2bits.RBPU = 0;
    TRISD = 00000000;
}

void main(void) {
    initPort();
    while(1){
        if(PORTBbits.RB0 != 1){
            __delay_ms(20);
            contador = contador + 1;
            if(contador == 5){
                contador = 1;
            }
            switch(contador){
                case 1:
                    Led1();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Led2();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Led3();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Led4();
                    break;                
            }
        }
    }            
}

void Led1(void){
    LATD = 10101010;
    if(speed == 1){
        __delay_ms(1000);
        LATD = 00000000;
        __delay_ms(1000);        
    }
    else if(speed == 2){
        __delay_ms(500);
        LATD = 00000000;
        __delay_ms(500);        
    }
    else if(speed == 3){
        __delay_ms(250);
        LATD = 00000000;
        __delay_ms(250);        
    }
    else if(speed == 4){
        __delay_ms(100);
        LATD = 00000000;
        __delay_ms(100);        
    }
    if(PORTBbits.RB1 == 0){
        __delay_ms(20);
        speed = speed + 1;
        if(speed == 5){
            speed = 1;
        }
    }
}

void Led2(void){
    LATD = 11111111;
    if(speed == 1){
        __delay_ms(1000);
        LATD = 00000000;
        __delay_ms(1000);        
    }
    else if(speed == 2){
        __delay_ms(500);
        LATD = 00000000;
        __delay_ms(500);        
    }
    else if(speed == 3){
        __delay_ms(250);
        LATD = 00000000;
        __delay_ms(250);        
    }
    else if(speed == 4){
        __delay_ms(100);
        LATD = 00000000;
        __delay_ms(100);        
    }
    if(PORTBbits.RB1 == 0){
        __delay_ms(20);
        speed = speed + 1;
        if(speed == 5){
            speed = 1;
        }
    }
}

void Led3(void){
    LATD = 01100110;
    if(speed == 1){
        __delay_ms(1000);
        LATD = 00000000;
        __delay_ms(1000);        
    }
    else if(speed == 2){
        __delay_ms(500);
        LATD = 00000000;
        __delay_ms(500);        
    }
    else if(speed == 3){
        __delay_ms(250);
        LATD = 00000000;
        __delay_ms(250);        
    }
    else if(speed == 4){
        __delay_ms(100);
        LATD = 00000000;
        __delay_ms(100);        
    }
    if(PORTBbits.RB1 == 0){
        __delay_ms(20);
        speed = speed + 1;
        if(speed == 5){
            speed = 1;
        }
    }
}

void Led4(void){
    LATD = 10011001;
    if(speed == 1){
        __delay_ms(1000);
        LATD = 00000000;
        __delay_ms(1000);        
    }
    else if(speed == 2){
        __delay_ms(500);
        LATD = 00000000;
        __delay_ms(500);        
    }
    else if(speed == 3){
        __delay_ms(250);
        LATD = 00000000;
        __delay_ms(250);        
    }
    else if(speed == 4){
        __delay_ms(100);
        LATD = 00000000;
        __delay_ms(100);        
    }
    if(PORTBbits.RB1 == 0){
        __delay_ms(20);
        speed = speed + 1;
        if(speed == 5){
            speed = 1;
        }
    }
}

 ```
````

Comment: Can you take us through your steps for programming the IC in proteus?

Comment: When trying to get the IC in proteus, I tried to open the project and it was corrupt and wouldn't let me open it.
So I have done it again.
When I have simulated the new project again to see the errors.
It has worked correctly.
So I guess it was all because the previous project was wrong.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: That's good that you were able to get it working. It may be worth writing your own answer for this question, in case anyone else has a similar issue.